# how to fnd if R is an order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

hello i have a upcoming quiz and I was solving practice problems that the instructor gave us.
But Im not sure how to approach this problem

the problem is: Let $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$, and $\mathcal{R}$ be a binary relation on $A\times A$ given by: $(a,b)\mathcal{R}(c,d) \iff a|c$ and $b|c$. Show that $\mathcal{R}$ is a order and draw its diagram.

I really don't know how to solve for transitivity and antisymmetricity.... detailed explanation will be very much appreaciated..
Thank you

Comment: This is a repeat of this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988200/how-to-show-that-rbinary-relation-on-a-x-a-is-an-order

Comment: yes... i checked that post but it only has explanation for reflexitivity which I already know.. I want to know about transitivity and antisymmetricity

Comment: That question is still active (the answer is only a few hours old) and asks about the 2 parts you care about as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not too hard, I mean, it's easy to think that: 
If $(a,b) \textbf{R} (c,d) and (c,d) \textbf{R} (e,f) \implies a \lvert c , b \lvert d , c \lvert e \wedge d \lvert f$ so if $c$ divides $e$ and $a$ divides $c$ then $a$ divides $e$, because the relation "divides" is transitive, the same with $b$. Therefore $(a,b) \textbf{R} (e,f)$ so it is transitive. For antisymmetry is routine for a positive set, I mean. Clearly if $(a,b) \textbf{R} (c,d) \wedge (c,d) \textbf{R} (a,b) \implies a \lvert c, b \lvert d \wedge c \lvert a, d \lvert b$ therefore $ a = c \wedge b = d$.
So it is transitive, anti symmetric and reflexive. Note that the anti symmetry works in this case because it is a positive set. If it is not a positive set then you have: 
If $ a \lvert b \wedge b\lvert a \implies \lvert a \rvert = \lvert b \rvert$.
Hope this helped!

Comment: Worth noting, I think, that while $a|c$ and $c|a$ implies $a=c$ for $a$ and $c$ elements of the set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, it’s not true for integers in general. ($2$ and $-2$ divide each other, but are not equal.)

Comment: Oops I forgot to add or put the absolute value. My bad. You are right man. Sorry. But in this set it works, but yeah.

Comment: thank u so much what a great answer.... just one more question, how would i draw a graph for this one? it seems like i should put (1,1) on the bottom and (1,2)(1,3)(1,4) on top of (1,1) and so on.... it is really confusing

Comment: Sorry for not answering, I did not see the comment. Mmmm for the graph I think the best way to go is to "see" or make $A \times A$, so that you can actually "see" all of its elements, then, as you said, clearly $(1,1)$ goes at the bottom, then I guess the next ones, by that I mean the next "line" or level", are the coordinates $(1,p) \wedge (p,1)$ with $p$ prime. Then the following are the ones divisible by the prime and so on.